# JAVA Inheriting static field from base class in the way that it will differ for every subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, static, field

I have a base class

```
public class base
{
    //some stuff
}
```

and several subclasses

```
public class sub1 extends base
{
static int variable;
}
public class sub2 extends base
{
static int variable;
}
```

etc

The static int variable exists in every subclass because I store in it information that is characteristic for every subclass. But it would be better if there was a way to move static int variable to base class in the way that it still will be different for every subclass.
In the way that it is now I am repeating myself, when adding some another subclass, it's a bad practice.

So anyone has some idea how to acomplish this? Maybe there's a design pattern that fits to this situation?

Comment: If the values are different, how are you repeating yourself?

Comment: Does the value for a given subclass change over time, or is it constant?

Comment: @Bohemian It doesn't.

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski When I create 2 objects of sub1 I want them to have the same value of variable but different than sub2 objects for example: `sub1 obj1 = new sub1();// value =x sub1 obj2 = new sub1();// value =x sub2 obj3 = new sub2();//value =y sub2 obj4 = new sub2();//value =y` Now imagine that I have 5 methods that uses static variable I have to implement them in every subclass BUT they are all the same - that's repeating myself

Answer (score 0):

You cannot move all the different static variables from derived classes into the base class, because `static` variables are one-per-class; you want your variables to be one-per-subclass, which is not allowed.

You could work around this issue by defining a registry of subclasses in your base class, and store the `int` for each subclass there. However, this would add a lot more complexity, and it is not clear how you would differentiate between subclasses in the superclass.

Your current solution appears optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a static field for this - that's not the way to go, because static fields of a subclass do not "override" those of a super class.

Instead, because the values are constant for a given class, use a final instance field:

```
public class Base {
    protected final int variable;
    public Base() {
        this(5);
    }
    protected Base(int v) {
        variable = v;
    }
}

public class Sub1 extends Base {
     private static int v = 7;
     public Sub1() {
        super(v);
    }
}
```

Now the variable is fixed and accessible to all instances.

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is that the example i posted is simplified ofc, and in the real code the variable is object (some kind of big object I mean) and there will be high ammount of subclasses objects made during the run of application, so making it non-static (making new variable for every object of the same subclass) will affect performance.

Comment: @Rotek see change to subclass to avoid recreating value. Also if Base is never used directly, consider making it `abstract` and deleting the default constructor

Answer (score -2):

You can certainly move variable into the base class, but it cannot be static.  Alternatively, you can make static getters which you override in each subclass. Here is an example of both:

```
public class base {
    protected int variable;
    protected static int getVariable() {
       return -1;
    }
}

public class Sub1 extends base {
    public Base() {
        variable = 0;
    }
    protected static int getVariable() {
        return 0;
    }
}
public class Sub2 extends base {
    public Sub2() {
        variable = 1;
    }
    protected static int getVariable() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

As a design principle, it is somewhat rare (in my opinion) that you genuinely want static methods. Usually you will have some instance of the class around that you are working with. If you want a whole bunch of objects to share some common behavior which you configure at runtime, you might want to check out the flyweight pattern.

Comment: Java doesn't allow overriding of static methods. What you are suggesting is simple a redefinition. Which of methods will be called is determined at compile time according to the type of reference variable. E.g.: `base b = new Sub2(); b.getVariable();` will return `-1`.

Comment: What is the point of a static getter method that gets variable if it returns a constant no matter what variable contains?

Comment: This is not about what is returned from method, this is about which static method is called. If in your code you call a static method using reference variable (`base b; b.getVariable()`), then type of that reference variable determine which method is called. If in your code you call a static method using class (`Sub2.getVariable()`), then method defined in that class will be called.

Comment: Try running the code. I assure you, you can instantiate a new Sub1(), and getVariable() will return you 1. You're right though, if you case it to Base it will no longer return 1.

Comment: `new Sub1().getVariable()` will return `1` - because `new Sub1()` returns 'invisible' reference variable of type `Sub1`. But `base b = new Sub1(); b.getVariable()` will return `-1` - beacuse reference variable `b` is of type `base` (although the object it references to is of type `Sub1`)